# Stop the FooBasic.com Spam

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, spam

This [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2762985/jessy) has started posting answers advertising FooBasic.com. I do not have any flags left today to flag the new answers as spam.

Comment: I somewhat expect they won't survive the minute

Comment: I take it the answer-bans are not working?

Comment: Done deleting all the spams...

Comment: I would hope that having three answers community deleted in the space of a couple of minutes triggers an answer ban...

Comment: Yes, yes it does.

Comment: It may amuse people to know that the first result for a google search of foobasic.com is this question. Somehow I don't think that was quite what the spammer had in mind

Comment: @Mysticial It's only three answers, unless he's using multiple accounts...

Comment: @animuson I just flagged two spam from a [new account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2763120/user2763120)

Comment: Meanwhile in YuppiAnswers...

Comment: I am not saying [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710539/i-am-using-foo-basic-ide-which-uses-classic-vb-code-to-create-a-dating-web-sit) is spam. But doesn't look like a question with good intention.